# Angular2: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, observable

I'm created my own Observable service

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ObservableService {
    data = [];
    @Output eventEmitter:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    setSharedData(key, value) {
        this.data[key] = value;
        this.eventEmitter.emit(this.data);
    }

    getSharedData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

And here is an usage example

```
ngOnInit() {
        this._observable.eventEmitter.subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
```

So currently while compiling it saying

```
app/services/data-observable.service.ts(6,5): error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Which is refers to this particular string,

```
@Output eventEmitter:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

But the service works perfect, any suggestions what is wrong?

Comment: As per https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html it should be `@Output() eventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the parentheses after `Output()`. Although `Output()` is not necessary within a service. This is only necessary in a component or directive, because then you can use the `(eventEmitter)="onEventEmit($event)"` notation within a template.

On the other hand you are missing a type annotation for the generic `EventEmitter<T>`:

```
eventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

or

```
eventEmitter: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Above that, `EventEmitters` should only be used inside `@Component`. If you want similar functionality, use `Subject` from `rxjs`.

```
subject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
```